Fastest way to load "maximally adversarial" text data into postgres
I have ~1TB of text data stored across a couple thousand compressed JSON files that I'd like to load into postgres. The problem with any of the obvious approaches like pg_bulkload or COPY is that the text data is likely to contain any given delimiter! Any ideas? Ideally some way to bulkload using file newlines as a separator

Transform the json to csv and use copy to move the content to the database.

The issue with translating to a CSV is that the text contains commas (and so, for instance the very first record I try to load pg_bulkload throws an error because pg_bulkload thinks I'm trying to load 38 columns instead of 1), I've found a specific workaround for this dataset (i.e. a character I know doesn't appear to use as delimiter) but I'm going to leave the question up for curiosity


if it is json you can load it as json. 2) if you convert an extract to CSV then the commas are escaped by definition. Can you explain what your actual problem is?


If the data are junk, what would you do with them inside the database?


I'm fairly certain there's no way to load as JSON directly (it always involves some kind of conversion or loading as JSONB) 2) The methods of converting to CSV simply add commas, they do not escape existing ones in the JSON (I could add a sanitize step, but at this scale that would take a lot of time)


I've found a few solutions:
(1) Use 2 double quotes as a separator (e.g. ""), for the data to be valid json, at least the double quote character will always be escaped in the data field, allowing you to convert to a CSV using jq (or a tool of choice) with "" as separator (enabling the use of fast ingest tools like pg_bulkload
(2) Load the data using a tool for parquet like pyarrow, then import to the database. I'm unsure how efficient this is--but parquet avoids the separator issue/supports loading from JSON natively
(3) Sanitize then load--you can escape commas in the text field. It'll be slow (sanitizing 3TB is expensive), but it will work
(4) Import as jsonb into postgres, then create a new table from the jsonb one. This will require at least 2x the disk space of your raw data
